# The displayed number of accounts 101 doesn't match the actual number of accounts

Tags: bug, user-accounts

It seems like 101 is the maximum displayed number of accounts. For example [Community Manager Shog9 ♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9) has 113 accounts, but his profile says 101:

[image]

**EDIT (2013-03-31): this bug has been fixed while fixing [another bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/227031/178179).**

Comment: 101 accounts ought to be enough for anybody.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Yes I think that staying at 69 accounts as you have right now is much better. Good for you!