# SE website not listed on my profile main page

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, linked-accounts

My profile main page (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/178179/franck-dernoncourt):

[image]

My SE websites (https://stackexchange.com/users/169656/franck-dernoncourt?tab=accounts)

[image]

"Software Recommendations" is missing on my profile main page. I think it's related to the repeatedly dismissed bug  [The displayed number of accounts 101 doesn't match the actual number of accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216288/178179)

Comment: I don't think it's related to that other bug. The 101 appears to be some hard coded limit, while this case is glitch in the server side cache storing the "5 top accounts" to be displayed in the per site profiles.

Comment: nice one, adding it to my to-do list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed in build rev `2014.3.31.2102` on meta and rev `2014.3.31.1501` on sites. The reason for this bug was a halfway implemented API call that only fetched the first page (100 accounts) + the Area 51 account (thus 101), instead of fetching all the pages. I guess when that was originally implemented the idea of an user having accounts on more than 100 network sites seemed outlandish.

Comment: Tell me you didn't set the new sanity check limit to 1000. If you did it, some future programmer (or even you! ;)) will have to fix it at some point. :D

Comment: The 101 mystery is now solved :)