# Users' account lists on Area51 are incomplete

Tags: bug, area-51

Example with a non-standard user:

- https://stackexchange.com/users/620/shog9?tab=accounts contains "Software Recommendations".
- http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/125?tab=accounts does not.

Example with a standard user:

- https://stackexchange.com/users/169656/franck-dernoncourt?tab=accounts contains "Software Recommendations".
- http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/51707?tab=accounts does not.

Why are users' account lists on Area51 incomplete?

Comment: Shog9 doesn't count, he's here to screw the databases :P Have you seen it with any more standard user?

Comment: @tohecz Sure, me. Question edited.

Comment: Looks like it's limited to 100 accounts only. The team never expected to have more than 100 sites when Area51 was launched so as a sanity check in the code, they limit to 100.

Comment: @ShadowWizard A bit like [The displayed number of accounts 101 doesn't match the actual number of accounts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216288/178179) I guess then.

Comment: Not a bit like, it's the exact same issue. Area51 is running under a different code branch that was never fixed like the [main code branch](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/227300/152859)